# Excel VBA - Shapes.AddPicture vs Pictures.Insert into spreadsheet from mapped drive

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using an Excel VBA macro to add images to my spreadsheet lists from a folder on our office server. The list exports from my database software with the containing folder and image name in Column A (e.g. `038/19761809.jpg`). I now need to send these documents to persons outside of my office without access to our server so I am trying to switch from using `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert` to using the *more correct*  `ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture`. The goal is to have the image files embed in the document rather than just linking to the files on our office server.

This code (using `Pictures.Insert`) inserts the images as links. When I email the spreadsheet to off-site users, the linked images "break" as recipient's computer cannot find them (because their computer is not on our local network).

```
Sub InsertPictures()
 Dim MyRange As String
 Dim picname As String
 Dim mySelectRange As String
 Dim rcell As Range
 Dim IntInstr As Integer
 Dim Mypath As String

 Mypath = "S:\pp4\images\"
 MyRange = "A2:A275"

 Range(MyRange).Select
 For Each rcell In Selection.Cells
    If Len(rcell.Value) > 0 Then
        picname = Mypath & rcell.Value
        mySelectRange = Replace(MyRange, "B", "A")
        IntInstr = InStr(mySelectRange, ":")
        mySelectRange = Left(mySelectRange, IntInstr - 1)
        do_insertPic picname, mySelectRange, rcell.Left, rcell.Top
     End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub do_insertPic(ByRef picname As String, ByRef MyRange As String, myleft As Integer, mytop As Integer)
    Dim rcell As Range
    Range(MyRange).Select
    On Error GoTo ErrNoPhoto

    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(picname).Select
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Selection
     .Left = myleft + 4
     .Top = mytop + 4
     .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
     .ShapeRange.Height = 115#
     .ShapeRange.Rotation = 0#
    End With
Exit Sub
ErrNoPhoto:
 MsgBox "Unable to Find Photo" 'Shows message box if picture not found
End Sub
```

I have modified my code to use the formatting for `Shapes.AddPicture`. Here is the new code:

```
Sub InsertPictures()
 Dim MyRange As String
 Dim picname As String
 Dim mySelectRange As String
 Dim rcell As Range
 Dim IntInstr As Integer
 Dim Mypath As String

 Mypath = "S:\pp4\images\"
 MyRange = "A2:A275"

 Range(MyRange).Select
 For Each rcell In Selection.Cells
    If Len(rcell.Value) > 0 Then
        picname = Mypath & rcell.Value
        mySelectRange = Replace(MyRange, "B", "A")
        IntInstr = InStr(mySelectRange, ":")
        mySelectRange = Left(mySelectRange, IntInstr - 1)
        do_insertPic picname, mySelectRange, rcell.Left, rcell.Top
     End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub do_insertPic(ByRef picname As String, ByRef MyRange As String, myleft As Integer, mytop As Integer)
    Dim rcell As Range
    Range(MyRange).Select
    On Error GoTo ErrNoPhoto

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=picname, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=myleft + 4, Top:=mytop + 4, LockAspectRatio:=msoTrue, Height:=115#, Rotation:=0#).Select
    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
ErrNoPhoto:
 MsgBox "Unable to Find Photo" 'Shows message box if picture not found
End Sub
```

When I try to run the new macro Excel just puts up my "Unable to Find Photo" error message. Can you help me find what I did wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Run you macro in the debugger and step through your code. You will be able to identify what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 extra arguments in `Shapes.AddPicture` (`LockAspectRatio`, `Rotation`), and a missing one (`Width`).

See more details about [Shapes.AddPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture), and your corrected code below:

```vb
Sub do_insertPic(ByRef picname As String, ByRef MyRange As String, myleft As Integer, mytop As Integer)

    Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Dim rcell As Range
    Range(MyRange).Select
    On Error GoTo ErrNoPhoto

    With sht.Shapes
        .AddPicture _
            Filename:=picname, _
            LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
            SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
            Left:=myleft + 4, _
            Top:=mytop + 4, _
            Width:=-1, _
            Height:=115

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
ErrNoPhoto:
    Debug.Print "Unable to Find Photo" 'Shows message box if picture not found
End Sub
```

PS: I recommend you to read about avoiding to use `.Select` in everything...

Comment: the arguments as double, since integer can't nearly handle the size