# Reading image in excel media folder using visual basic

Tags: excel, vba

I need to dynamically add images to the excel sheet, however the images can't be tied to a specific path since the file is meant to be shared. By dynamically, i mean i want an image to be placed on the sheet when a function is called. I've made that part work, however if i move the picture files the images are lost in the sheet.

If i insert an image into excel, i can see that image stored in that excel files' media folder, however i can't figure out how to reference it.

I also thought about encoding the image to base64, then decode it from excel when the workbook is launched and place it somewhere in the filesystem, however i can't figure out how to do that either since all of the examples only show decoding a string, not an entire file.

To clarify: i want the pictures to persist regardless if i have them on my filesystem or not, just like they do when i insert them manually.

The code for inserting images:

```
Sub InsertPictureHyperlink(row As Integer, column As Integer, path As String, extnsn As String)
    Dim image As Picture
    Dim image_path As String
    Dim image_name As String
    Dim appDataPath As String
    image_path = Environ$("AppData") + "\appres\" + extnsn + ".png"
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column)
        Set image = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CStr(image_path))
        image.Top = .Top
        image.Left = .Left
        image.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        image.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        image.ShapeRange.Width = 25
        image.ShapeRange.Height = 25
    End With
    With ActiveSheet
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Shapes(image.name), Address:=path
    End With
    ActiveCell.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Put all pictures on a hidden sheet. Then copy them to the sheet you need whenver you want to *"insert"* them.

Comment: "I've made that part work" - can you post the code for this.

Comment: If your code is secret, we cannot help you modifying it to do what you ask for. And why do you feel the need to encode it?

Comment: @CDP1802 Sure, i'll reply with a pastebin link at some point during the day.

Comment: No need of any link. Please, edit your question and paste the code as text. Then format it as code (between ```)...

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I think that might do the trick! Thank you! I'll try that and get back to you on if it worked. Could you post this as an answer so that i can accept it if i manage to get it to work?

Comment: Please, add the next two parameters: `LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True`. `.Insert(filename:=image_path, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)`.

Comment: Use `Shapes.addPicture()` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69624158/)

Comment: @FaneDuru unfortunately, it tells me that a named argument is not found for ```ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filename:=image_path, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)```

Comment: Ups... Try `ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPictue(filename:=image_path, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)`. I was not atentive enough to the function you use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to transport the pictures with the Excel file and you don't want them as pictures in an extra folder, a solution can be to insert all the pictures into a hidden worksheet and copy them from there onto the desired sheet later.

This way your pictures are saved within the Excel file at any time.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was a perfect and easy solution.